# Text Underline Animation Left to Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The Navigation Links on hover ease in a underline from left to right and ease out right to left. I would like to make it so that both the ease in & ease out go from left to right. How can I adjust the ease out?

http://jsfiddle.net/2tycjc82/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="" class="in" style="display: inline-block;"> 
            <svg class="navinstagram" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 155.2 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 155.2 144;" xml:space="preserve">
                <path  d="M42.7,122.7H21.3V54h21.4V122.7z M32,44.6c-6.8,0-12.4-5.6-12.4-12.4c0-6.8,5.5-12.4,12.4-12.4c6.8,0,12.4,5.5,12.4,12.4C44.4,39,38.9,44.6,32,44.6z M122.7,122.7h-21.3V89.3c0-8-0.1-18.2-11.1-18.2c-11.1,0-12.8,8.7-12.8,17.6v34H56.1V54h20.5v9.4h0.3c2.8-5.4,9.8-11.1,20.2-11.1c21.6,0,25.6,14.2,25.6,32.7V122.7z"/>
                <g>
                    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.9,120c0.7-0.1,1-0.5,1-1.1c0-0.8-0.5-1.1-1.4-1.1H150v4h0.6V120h0.7l0,0l1.1,1.7h0.6L151.9,120L151.9,120z M151.3,119.6h-0.7v-1.4h0.9c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.6C152.4,119.5,151.9,119.6,151.3,119.6z"/>
                    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.3,116c-2.1,0-3.8,1.7-3.8,3.8c0,2.1,1.7,3.8,3.8,3.8c2.1,0,3.8-1.7,3.8-3.8C155.2,117.6,153.5,116,151.3,116z M151.3,123.1c-1.8,0-3.3-1.4-3.3-3.3c0-1.9,1.4-3.3,3.3-3.3c1.8,0,3.3,1.4,3.3,3.3C154.6,121.7,153.2,123.1,151.3,123.1z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </a>

        <a href="" class="logo logocolorchng" style="display: inline-block;">Logo </a>

        <a id="toggle-menu">
            <div> 
                <span class="top"></span>
                <span class="middle"></span>
                <span class="bottom"></span>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
    <div class="nav">

        <div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="navlist"><a href="" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Home</a></li>            
                <li class="navlist"><a href="#panel2" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Work</a></li>
                <li class="navlist"><a href="#wrapper" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*navlist*/
.navigation{
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.navlist {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navlist:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1.5px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navlist:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
/*----/----navlist*/

/*global styles*/
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1.05em;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
a {
    font-size:1.05em;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    background:transparent;
    color: grey;
    border:none;
    letter-spacing:0.15em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----/----global styles*/

/*navigation icon*/
#toggle-menu {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#toggle-menu div {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.header #toggle-menu span {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s    ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}
#toggle-menu span.top {
    top: 0px;
}
#toggle-menu span.middle {
    top: 6px;
}
#toggle-menu span.bottom {
    top: 12px;
}
/*----/----navigation icon*/

/*navigation background transition*/
.bg {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navfade {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.header .logo { /* Before scroll */
    color: white;
}
.bg .logo { /* After scroll */
    color: #545454;
}
.navinstagram {
    fill: #fff
}
.bg .navinstagram{
    fill: #545454;
}

#toggle-menu span{
    background: #fff;
}
.bg #toggle-menu span {
    background: #545454;
}
/*----/----navigation background transition*/

/*navigation icon animation*/
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top    0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.top, #toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.middle {
    top: 6px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.middle {
    opacity: 0;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.bottom {
    top: 6px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/*----/----navigation icon animation*/

/*Nav Bar*/
.header {
    /*border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);*/
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    /*background: none;*/
}
.whitenavbar {
    background: white;

}
.nav {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    top: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #545454;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
.nav li {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.seemore {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#navpromo {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navpromo ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.want{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.check{
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) {
    .want{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .check{
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }   
}
.instbtn-cont {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    color: grey;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover {
    border: none;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-1 {
    -webkit-animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
    animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-2 {
    -webkit-animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
    animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-3 {
    -webkit-animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
    animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-4 {
    -webkit-animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
    animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-1 {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-2 {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-3 {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-4 {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    54% {
        height: 0;
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    55% {
        height: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes move1 {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    54% {
        height: 0;
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    55% {
        height: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    50% {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes move2 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    50% {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
        left: 100%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move3 {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    54% {
        height: 0;
        top: 100%;
    }
    55% {
        height: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes move3 {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    54% {
        height: 0;
        top: 100%;
    }
    55% {
        height: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move4 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    55% {
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
        right: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes move4 {
    0% {
        width: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    55% {
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
        right: 100%;
    }
}
/*----/----Nav Bar*/

/*in*/
.in {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
    border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
/*----/----in*/

/*logo*/
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:.8em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
/*----/----logo*/

/****landscape****/
@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) { 
    .nav li{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .navlist:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 1.5px;
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
        transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    }
    .navlist:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
        background: grey;
        transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
    }
}
/*----/----Landscape*/
```

jQuery:

```
/*navigation icon animation*/
var trigger = 'X';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggle-menu').click(function () {
        trigger = 'X';
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active')

    });

    /* click outside of nav to trigger navigation icon animation*/
    $(document).click(function () {


        if (trigger == 'X') {
            $("#toggle-menu").toggleClass();
            trigger = 'ham';
        }

    });
    $("nav").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
    /*----/----navigation icon animation*/

    /*toggle menu*/
    jQuery("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
        jQuery(".nav").slideToggle();
        if($("div.header").hasClass("whitenavbar") == false){
            $("div.header").addClass("whitenavbar bg navup ");
        }else{
            $("div.header").removeClass("whitenavbar bg navup");
        }

    });



    /* click outside of nav to close toggle*/
    $(document).click(function () {
        $(".nav").hide();
    });
    $("#toggle-menu").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
    /*----/----toggle menu*/

    /*navigation background fade in fade out */
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var dist = $('#panel2').offset().top;
        console.log(dist);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > dist) {
            $('.header').addClass('bg');
            $('.header').addClass('navfade');
        }
        else {
            $('.header').removeClass('bg');
        }


    });


    $('.scroll').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });

    /*----/-----navigation background fade in fade out */

});
```

Comment: So what do you expect will happen when user hover on an item then immediately move out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some changes to your css:

```
.navlist:after {
    ...
    float: right; /* Add this line */
}

.navlist:hover:after {
    ...
    float: left; /* Add this line */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2tycjc82/2/

But as I commented. There's a not-so-nice result when user hover in then immediately hover out.

Comment: This works thank you! I noticed that in Internet Explorer browsers it now shows a half the underline height for "work" & "contact" than "home". The height is set to be 2px. I've tried adding overflow: visible to  .navlist:after to fix the bug but it doesn't work??

Comment: Isn't it because .navlist:after has a height of 1.5px?